# How to make element grow in height with its parent (no parent height specified)

Tags: html, css

This question has been asked a couple of times, but all are at least 4-5 years old from what I see. So I am wondering if there is a new better/easier way to do this.

I got a menu with a button in it, the menu will change in size according to the logo that is posted in it. So when I upload a large logo the menu is stretched in height, but the button stays the same height. The menubar has no specified height so `height:100%` will not work.

Image for more clarity:

[image]

The white bar is my menu, and the grey area my button.

The html markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top m-b-0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg " href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="ti-menu"></i></a>
        <div class="top-left-part"><a class="logo" href="index.php"><img style="height:100%;" src="logo.png" alt="home" /></a></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-left hidden-xs">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open-close hidden-xs waves-effect waves-light"><i class="icon-arrow-left-circle ti-menu"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b class="hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</b> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user animated flipInY">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Relevant css:

```
.navbar-default {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.navbar-header {
    background: #fff !important;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-top-links > li > a {
    color: #1f7db1;
    padding: 0 12px;
    line-height: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.navbar-top-links > li > a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Is javaScript an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using CSS this could be down with `display:table` on parent and `display:table-cell` on the children. but i don't suggest you use that in your current situation because you have a bunch of divs there, navbars etc.

so i made a JQ solution. i hope you don't mind. it's very easy to understand and easy to modify if needed.

let me know if it helps

see fiddle here > [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26230/)

JQ code :

```
var newHeight = $(".top-left-part").height()
$(".pull-right > li.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle").height(newHeight)
```

to align the text vertically i added

```
a.dropdown-toggle {
    display:flex
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I already fixed it with javascript but this is fewer code than what I had. Also the text is centered vertically now.

Comment: to align the text vertically i added `display:flex` on the `a.dropdown-toggle` together with `align-items:center;`

Comment: Yeah I noticed, nice job

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof-of-concept solution that may help. This solution uses CSS only and does not require JavaScript.

Let `.wrap` be the parent container that contains your navigation, logo and so on.

In `.wrap`, create a protected area to the right that will contain your button.  Do this by specifying `padding-right: 100px` (for example) and then specify `position: relative`.

You can now define an element called `.right-panel` that will contain your button and so on.  For `.right-panel`, specify `position: absolute` and set the offsets as `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` to force it to keep to the height of the parent block, and then `right: 0` to pin it to the right of the parent and then set the `width: 100px` (for example).

As you change the content in the parent container, the `.right-panel` will take on the height of the parent in a responsive manner.

The limitation here is that you need to specify a width for the right-hand side panel/element, which may not be too limiting since you know something about the design of the button (such as its dimensions).

You might need to specify a `min-height` for the parent `.wrap` for cases where you have either no logo or a logo whose height is less than that of the intrinsic height of the button.

**Note:** If you are using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, you may need to do some more work fit this into a floated parent, but I have not tried it.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.right-panel {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Some header that can be text or a logo.</h1>
  <p>Some content and so on.</p>
  <div class="right-panel">
    <p>A button or whatever.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works also, but centering the text will probably be an issue.

Comment: Centering the text is not an issue, horizontally with `text-align` center and vertically using `flex` (or CSS table-cell), which would be required even with  a fixed height solution (using JavaScript).